# Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, talend

I have a sql query that i am having issues executing inside my etl job:

```
 "delete" + context.Redshift_data_lake_venus + "." + context.cntx_destination_table_name + 
 " where  lngGameHistory  in  (select b.lngGameHistory
from  " + context.Redshift_data_lake_venus + ".idbs_tblgamehistory b
where " + context.cntx_date_filter_name + " >=  '" + context.cntx_date_id_begin + "' and  " + context.cntx_date_filter_name + " <= '" + context.cntx_date_id_end + "' )"
```

I can execute the hardcoded subquery in redshift but its not working in my etl job

The error is as follows:

> tRedshiftRow_5 - Amazon Invalid operation: This type of
>   correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;
>   Amazon Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery
>   pattern is not supported due to internal error;[FATAL]:
>   tgtimdagamespos.job_incremental_idbs_tblgamehistorybay_6_0.job_Incremental_IDBS_TblGameHistoryBay
>   - tMSSqlInput_1 Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Can someone advice me on what i am doing wrong? How the code should be modified?

I am trying to execute this on my etl job using a redshift component

> tRedshiftRow_5 - Amazon Invalid operation: This type of
>   correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;

Comment: have you read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html ? Does that help with your question?

Comment: The 'where' clause seems to be a date comparison. What is the type of variables context.cntx_date_filter_name, date_id_begin , date_id_end ? If they are in Date Type, perhaps you'll need to convert them into String values before comparing

Comment: Can you post the actual SQL being executed i.e. that is generated by the code above?